# Can anyone identify this beach?

Tags: identify-this, beaches

Can anyone identify the location of this image?

[image: Unknown Location Image]

A few websites claim that it is from Neil Island in the Andaman & Nicobar Islands of India. But it is not correct as far as I know. None of my friends who visited Neil Island recollect seeing such a place there.

Replies with proofs (i.e. without guess-work like "It could be xyz..." ) like similar photographs taken or with lat-long coordinates will be extremely helpful.

Comment: It looks staggeringly photoshopped, but we'll be generous and assume that i's just tropical lighting and some generous levels/saturation tweaking.

Comment: The pieces are real, but the colors have definitely been "enhanced".

Comment: I got the picture from an advertisement on a travel agency's website. That should explain the colors ;-)

Comment: Hm... Lost s01e01? :D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Railay Beach area in Krabi Province, Thailand.  The karst outcroppings are at the south end of "sunset" beach.

Comment: Headbang moment. Limestone Karst outcrops - How did I miss them? 

Thanks Tom

Comment: Here's the image, with location, on Shutterstock: http://www.shutterstock.com/pic-121560010/stock-photo-railay-beach-in-krabi-thailand.html (Found with TinEye)

Comment: +1 Here's a [page of a local resort](http://thalanebayvilla.com/beach/railay-beach/) with two near-identical shots from slightly different angles (confirming it's not just one mislabeled photo)

Answer (score 2):

It reminded me of the classic Halong Bay shots.
Google image search included "Neil Island" in the search box.
Replacing that with "Halong" gave several appropriate hits including [**this 1440 x 900 version**](http://cdn29.us2.fansshare.com/pictures/railaybeach/railay-beach-map-1639050968.jpg)  correctly identifying it as Railay beach - as Tom has already advised.

Also [**here**](http://cdn29.us2.fansshare.com/pictures/railaybeach/railay-beach-map-1639050968.jpg) at 1440 x 810